# How to get the socket object in node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I am making an app with node.js(express)+socket.io and I am wondering how I can use the socket object which is the parameter of `io.on('connection',function(socket){...` from outside like routes files in the `routes` folder

app.js

```
app.get('/foo/:id?', routes.foo);
```

routes/foo.js

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  //do something with socket such as socket.join()
};
```

any ideas or tips would be appreciated.

**edited**
My goal is to let a user who accesses `'/foo/:id?'` join the socket.io's room(https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) named `id?'`.
So I would like to call `socket.join('req.params.id')` at

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  //HERE
};
```

Comment: You can access the underlying `Socket` via `req.connection`.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for commenting.But `Socket` I'm talking about is the parameter of `socket.io`'s callback.I've peeked what req.connection have though I coudln't see anything related to socket.io in it or am I missing something?

Comment: req.connection is the Node.js `socket` object.  Not sure what is available for socket.io, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [express.io](http://express-io.org/)

It's really easy to implement and you could do this:

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  req.io.join(req.params.id); // The client for the request joins to the room with name req.params.id
};
```